# estimated standard error for mean of Bernoulli random variables

Tags: parameter-estimation, standard-error

I know that if $X_1,...X_n$ are Bernoulli(p) then to calculate the estimated standard error is $$\hat \sigma_{\bar X_n}= \sqrt{\frac{\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_i (\bar X_n - X_i)^2} {n}}$$  however, often, I see that we simply replace the sample mean in the standard error formula $\sqrt{\frac{p (1-p)}{n}}$  which results in:$$\hat \sigma_{\bar X_n}= \sqrt {\frac{\bar X_n (1- \bar X_n) }{n}}$$ are these two the same?if so, how do we show that they are the same?

Comment: Try it with $n=2$ and $X_1=0$ and $X_2=1$.  Your first expression gives $\sqrt{\frac14}$ while your second gives $\sqrt{\frac18}$.  To get them equal you need the first to be  $\sqrt{\frac{\frac{1}{n} \sum_i (\bar X_n - X_i)^2} {n}}$ or your second to be $\sqrt {\frac{\bar X_n (1- \bar X_n) }{n-1}}$

Answer (score 2):

Since each $X_i \in \{0,1\}$, we observe that $X_i^2 = X_i$ for each $i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$.  I will use the notation $$\bar X = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i.$$  Equivalently, $$\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = n \bar X.$$

Then $$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2 
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \left( X_i^2 - 2\bar X X_i - \bar X^2 \right) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n X_i - 2\bar X \sum_{i=1}^n X_i + n \bar X^2 \\
&= n \bar X - 2 \bar X (n \bar X) + n \bar X^2 \\
&= n \bar X - n \bar X^2 \\
&= n \bar X (1 - \bar X).
\end{align}$$

It follows that
$$\frac{1}{n(n-1)} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2 = \frac{\bar X (1 - \bar X)}{n-1}.$$

We can see that if we had used the biased, Bessel-uncorrected sample variance, which is the maximum-likelihood estimate for the variance, $$\hat \sigma^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2$$ rather than the unbiased, [Bessel-corrected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction) sample variance
$$s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2,$$

then the two formulas would be equivalent.  Specifically,

$$\frac{\hat \sigma}{\sqrt{n}} = \sqrt{\frac{\bar X(1-\bar X)}{n}},$$ but
$$\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}} = \sqrt{\frac{\bar X (1-\bar X)}{n-1}}.$$

Comment: thanks for the clear description! Does replacing the parameter with the sample mean in the formula of the standard error work for all parametric distributions say Poisson etc. ?